Updating Linux server is failing with the error "dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-server"
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.54.8) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in 
import debian.deb822
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debian'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-server:
ubuntu-server depends on update-notifier-common; however:
Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
update-notifier-common
ubuntu-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debian' suggests that somebody has upgraded Python3 from the original version. If so, revert to that original version. The newer version lacks vital modules.
